# Puzzles about python argparse.add_arguments methods

Tags: python, argparse

When I call the `add_argument` method in `argparse.ArgumentParser`, why do I need to transmit two arguments as optional arguments? For example:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='try')
ap.add_argument('-f','--foo')
ap.add_argument('position')
```

What does the `'-f'` mean here?

Comment: All of `add_argument`'s parameters and their meanings are documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument

Comment: In general, you dont have to pass 2 arguments, you can pass only one. That should give you the ability to set shortcuts for flags, can be useful when there are many of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a shortcut. You can pass your argument either with --foo or -f.
For example,  `python filename.py -f arg` or  `python filename.py --foo arg` Moreover, you can leave out either one of the two if you like